# For an eCommerce application using Stripe and my own database, where should I store products and orders?

Tags: mongodb, stripe-payments, react-fullstack

My fullstack React eCommerce application interacts with Stripe using my Express backend.

I need the client to be able to perform CRUD operations on products and orders, and as such they are currently stored in my mongoDB database.

However, I have discovered that interacting with Stripe's API is significantly easier if products (and thus orders) are stored on their database too.

As such, I am considering using both databases as sources of truth. However, this means that every CUD operation on one would need to be reflected in the other, making things more complex.

What is the best approach to this predicament? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on your use-case and how you'd like to structure your integration. You're correct that it would make it easier to integrate with Stripe's API if you have the products and other information stored on Stripe. Stripe does provide a way for you to listen for any changes made to an object and update your own database accordingly using Webhooks [1].

You can build a webhook endpoint and listen to a variety of events in order to receive updates in real-time. This would allow you to maintain your own database without worrying about writing a script that polls API to retrieve the latest state of data/objects.

[1] https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks

Comment: Hi thanks for the response. I am familiar with Webhooks, so I believe I'd be able to integrate them. That being said, are you suggesting that actively maintaining both my own database as well as Stripe's is the best integration for my scenario? Like I said, the client needs to be able to perform lots of CRUD on products and orders.

Comment: Hi @hanzo, with webhooks, I've noticed that, when a product is created on Stripe, `product.created` runs (with no priceId on the resulting product), then `price.created` runs and finally `product.updated` runs (resulting product now contains the created priceId). Whilst I could use the first two events to create a product in my own database, this would require two separate mongoDB calls. I feel like I could also use `product.updated` to achieve this in one mongoDB call, but then I'd need to include some checking logic in my `product.updated` case. Which should I use?